# java.sql.SQLException: Cannot issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery(): Transfering values from MySQL to Excel

Tags: java, mysql, apache-poi

I have this program that transfers data from My MySQL table to an Excel file called Person.xls. I tried substituting "SELECT * FROM Applicant" to the String sql and the program worked, but once I use the longer query in my code, I get the error

"java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()."

Here is my code:

```
`package ExcelTest;

 import java.io.*;
 import java.sql.*;
 import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
 import java.util.*;

 public class ExcelDao {

 private Connection connection = null;

 public ExcelDao()
 throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

 // Create MySQL database connection
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

 String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + "mydb";
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "p@ssword");
 }

 public void generateXls(String tablename, String filename)
 throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {

 // Create new Excel workbook and sheet
 HSSFWorkbook xlsWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
 HSSFSheet xlsSheet = xlsWorkbook.createSheet();
 short rowIndex = 0;

 // Execute SQL query
 Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
 connection.setAutoCommit(false);
 stmt.execute("start transaction");
 String sql = "drop function if exists educAttainment;\n" +
    "DELIMITER //\n" +
    "create function educAttainment(idLevel int) returns VARCHAR(45)\n" +
    "begin\n" +
    "   declare educAttain VARCHAR(45);\n" +
    "       if idLevel = 1 then\n" +
    "       set educAttain := 'Elementary';\n" +
    "    elseif idLevel = 2 then\n" +
    "       set educAttain := 'High School';\n" +
    "   elseif idLevel = 3 then\n" +
    "       set educAttain := 'College';\n" +
    "   else \n" +
    "       set educAttain := 'Invalid';\n" +
    "    end if;\n" +
    "    return educAttain;\n" +
    "end //\n" +
    "SELECT CONCAT(a.familyname, \", \", a.firstName, \" \", a.middleName) as \"Name\",    a.dateOfBirth as \"Birthdate\", c.companyName as \"Assignment\", p.position as \"Position\", CONCAT(educAttainment(ed.idLevel), \"-\", ed.course) as \"Educational Attainment/Course\", a.address as \"Address\", e.dateOfEmployment as \"Date Started\", e.status as \"Employment Status\", CONCAT(d.startOfContract, \"-\", d.endOfContract) as \"Present Contract\"                    \n" +
    "FROM Applicant a, DeploymentDetails d, EmployeeDetail e, Company c, Position p, EducationalBackground ed\n" +
    "WHERE a.applicantNumber = e.applicantNumber && e.applicantNumber = d.applicantNumber && d.idCompany = c.idCompany && d.idPosition = p.idPosition && a.applicantNumber = ed.applicantNumber";
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
 //stmt.execute("commit");
 // Get the list of column names and store them as the first
 // row of the spreadsheet.
 ResultSetMetaData colInfo = rs.getMetaData();
 List<String> colNames = new ArrayList<String>();
 HSSFRow titleRow = xlsSheet.createRow(rowIndex++);

 for (int i = 1; i <= colInfo.getColumnCount(); i++) {
  colNames.add(colInfo.getColumnName(i));
  titleRow.createCell((short) (i-1)).setCellValue(
    new HSSFRichTextString(colInfo.getColumnName(i)));
  xlsSheet.setColumnWidth((short) (i-1), (short) 4000);
 }

 // Save all the data from the database table rows
 while (rs.next()) {
  HSSFRow dataRow = xlsSheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
  short colIndex = 0;
  for (String colName : colNames) {
    dataRow.createCell(colIndex++).setCellValue(
      new HSSFRichTextString(rs.getString(colName)));
  }
 }

 // Write to disk
 xlsWorkbook.write(new FileOutputStream(filename));
 }

 // Close database connection
 public void close() throws SQLException {
 connection.close();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 try {
  ExcelDao excelDao = new ExcelDao();
  excelDao.generateXls("person", "person.xls");
  excelDao.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 }
```

`

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Isn't the error self-explanatory? You're trying to drop a function with `executeQuery()` which is only supposed to be used when querying the data (e.g. `select`). I guess you need to use `executeUpdate()`.

Comment: Ohh I see. So maybe I should execute that one first then SELECT?

Comment: Yes, it would be better to split these things into update and query.

Comment: Ok I'm getting a weird error now. It says on my console that my syntax is incorrect, but when I use the same query on my MySQL, it works fine